# C# Functor for returning data without taking parameters

Tags: .net, delegates

Just as there are functors like Action, Func, Comparison, is there one which allows me to call a method that returns data and does not take any parameters?

**More Info**
eg: Action action, here action could take a method like `void DoWork(int i)`

I was wondering if there is a similarly defined delegate/functor that allows me to set action to a method like `int DoWork()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx), `Func<int>` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question,

I should have looked...  Func has a definition that allows you to call it without any parameters and returns a value. `Func<TResult>`

So in my case it would be `Func<int> action`, which would allow me to set action to `int DoWork()`;

Answer (score 0):

```
 // declaration
 public delegate int WillDoWork();
 // usage
 public event WillDoWork DoWork();
 ...
 ...
 // calling
 if (DoWork != null) {
     int a=DoWork();
 }
```